# ConfigurationManager vs Properties

Tags: c#, .net

What's the best practice to save user settings in .net C# applications? It seems to me it should be using code like:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["UserSetting"]
```

But there's also this `ConfigurationManager` class. Is any of these deprecated? What's the best usage scenario for each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ConfigurationManager is a general purpose set of classes to manipulate application and web configuration files and their structures. Properties.Settings is a subset of this functionality allowing the quick and simply manipulation of the Application Settings portion of that file.

I've only ever used Properties.Settings for my user specific stuff, I use the rest of the application config file for technical application stuff like Unity and NLog configuration. Only real benefit from Properties.Settings is that the values are visibile in the VS.net designer, which is quite useful.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems I should stick to Properties, I just intend to save 4-5 user settings.